# Why am i getting undefined when trying to get a single element?

Tags: json, api, next.js

Why am i getting undefined of my id? I am creating an app with NextJS and i am trying to do a route to get an especific element by its id. This is my route:

```
const { events } = require('../../../db.json')

const handler = async (req , res) => {
    const method = req.method;
    const evt = events.filter((ev) => ev.id === req.query.params.id); 

    if(method === 'GET'){
        return res.status(201).json(evt);
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET']);
        res.status(405).json({message:`Method ${method} is not allowed`})
    }
    
}
```

For some reason i get this error when i go to `http://localhost:3000/api/events/1`

I am using json web server so i have my api also running in port 3001 so at `http://localhost:3001/api/events/1` it works and show the corresponding id but why is not working in port 3000 also?

Comment: id is not a param. If you want to access the id as a param you should request your api like follow: http://localhost:3000/api/events/?id=1

Comment: `localhost:3000/api/events/?id=1 ` brings me all my events instead of just the one with the id = 1 @JairoPy

Comment: try localhost:3000/api/events?id=1 without the / after events

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your code to the following:

```
    const { events } = require('../../../db.json');

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  const method = req.method;
  const id = req.query.id;
  const evt = events.filter((ev) => ev.id === id);

  if (method === 'GET') {
    return res.status(201).json(evt);
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET']);
    res.status(405).json({ message: `Method ${method} is not allowed` });
  }
};
```

Comment: I already tried this but i get an empty array

Comment: I updated the code, if you're still getting an empty array make sure that your events array contains an object with an id property that matches the id you're passing in the query string.